# ¿Qué forma necesitan para hacer una regresión logística?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

Intenté ajustar una logística de regresión sobre un conjunto de datos. Me parece que hay buenas formas:

```
np.shape(x_train) (766, 497)
np.shape(x_test)  (766, 4)
```

Pero cuando aplico logreg.fit:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(x_train, y_train)
print('Accuracy of Logistic regression classifier on training set: {:.2f}'
     .format(logreg.score(x_train, y_train)))
print('Accuracy of Logistic regression classifier on test set: {:.2f}'
     .format(logreg.score(x_test, y_test)))
```

Me devuelve:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-a95a4aac2b3c> in <module>
      1 from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
      2 logreg = LogisticRegression()
----> 3 logreg.fit(x_train, y_train)
      4 print('Accuracy of Logistic regression classifier on training set: {:.2f}'
      5      .format(logreg.score(x_train, y_train)))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_logistic.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
   1525 
   1526         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse='csr', dtype=_dtype, order="C",
-> 1527                          accept_large_sparse=solver != 'liblinear')
   1528         check_classification_targets(y)
   1529         self.classes_ = np.unique(y)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    758                         dtype=None)
    759     else:
--> 760         y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
    761         _assert_all_finite(y)
    762     if y_numeric and y.dtype.kind == 'O':

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in column_or_1d(y, warn)
    795         return np.ravel(y)
    796 
--> 797     raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
    798 
    799 

ValueError: bad input shape (766, 4)
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Significado de: ValueError with shapes or dimensions](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/401368/significado-de-valueerror-with-shapes-or-dimensions)

Answer (score -2):

Basado en la documentación de scikit-learn:

> X: {Array like of shape (n_samples, n_features)
>   Y: {Array like of shape (n_samples,)

Es decir, la estructura de y_train debe ser (766, 1).
Un código ejemplo mínimo sería el siguiente:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

x_train = np.array(
    [
        [0, 0],
        [0, 1],
        [1, 0],
        [1, 1]
    ]
)
y_train = np.array(
    [
        [0],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1]
    ]
)

print(f'X shape: {x_train.shape}\tY shape: {y_train.shape}')

# Esto imprime
# X shape: (4, 2)    Y shape: (4, 1)

logreg = LogisticRegression()
trained_lr = logreg.fit(x_train, y_train)

print(f'Accuracy of logistic regression classifier on training set: {trained_lr.score(x_train, y_train):.4f}')
```

Referencia:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.fit